# Iframe video list

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm trying to create a video list from different sources. Video list from different source included youtube also. The following code will create video list. My problem is that the list didn't change source after end of the current video.

I need to implement auto next function.

```
<iframe id="videoarea" controls="controls" allow="autoplay" autoplay="true" poster="" src="" onended="nexxt()"></iframe>
<ul id="playlist">
  <li movieurl="https://www.youtube.com/embed/v0kOcitjuRw" moviesposter="">Happy Fit</li>
  <li movieurl="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nWHpU7H7Clc">see</li>
  <li movieurl="https://anyothersite.com/embed/urlvedio">other</li>
</ul>
```

```
$(function () {
  $("#playlist li").on("click", function () {
    $("#videoarea").attr({
      "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
      "poster": "",
      "autoplay": "autoplay"
    })
  })
  $("#videoarea").attr({
    "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl"),
    "poster": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("moviesposter")
  })
})
function nexxt()
{

  $("#videoarea").attr({
    "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
    "poster": "",
    "autoplay": "autoplay"
  })
  $("#videoarea").attr({
    "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl"),
    "poster": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("moviesposter")
  })
}
```

Comment: `onended` event only works for Audio and Video only. You can not apply this event on iframe.

Comment: @Sami Ahmed Siddiqui is there any option to accomplish this ?

Comment: You may do this with `video` tag. If you just need to load the videos from Youtube then you can Youtube API which may do the job but if you are going with different source there might be an issue while achieving this due to having `CORS`

Comment: @ Sami Ahmed Siddiqui it is difficult to detect end of the video while video tag doesn't support youtube